# Should I test the service or the route?

Tags: node.js, express, testing, integration-testing, supertest

I want to make integration tests in my node app. I have express endpoint, for example: `POST: /users`. This endpoint runs the User service to create a new user.

So I have the following dir structure:

```
routes
  users
    create.js // router.post('/users', ...);

services
  users
    create.js // actual user creation implementation
```

As you can see, the `routes/users/create.js` runs the `services/users/create.js` which does just anything and returns a response to the router and then the router sends back to the client.

I want to test it. As I said, should I test the route (using supertest or a kind) or the service or both?

Comment: It's up to you. If you go for testing the route way, you're able to test network infrastructure as well but it becomes more flaky.

Comment: I think Im going to test the whole route and for independent modules (modules that don't import any other modules), I will make a unit test which going to check them individually. Is it a good practice?

Comment: Yeah, it seems nice to me. My two cents is "test happy case using integration type of tests (calls real API)" and "test edge cases using unit tests" so that you can have few slow running integration tests and let unit tests cover the gap (edge cases). If you're further looking for api testing best practices or something similar, please go check out this wonderful article - http://blog.codepipes.com/testing/software-testing-antipatterns.html#anti-pattern-8---running-tests-manually

Answer (score 0):

As you may know there are three different types of tests:

- Integration
- End-to-end
- Unit

Testing your router will cause the invocation of the other functions in your router and it'll go all the way through the path of calling everything! this is only in a scenario where you use everything as is and don't create mock or spy for those functions.

Testing a router is more of an End-To-End testing than unit testing.

If you want to use any sort of fakes (mock, spy) then you have to be careful since not always you're allowed to do it ( if you basically have an unmanaged  dependency like a shared database between more than one service. you can only use fakes in this scenario ). other than that using mocks brings test fragility and violates resistance to regression (how much code/branches you've covered) and resistance to refactoring (how likely it is if you change any code your test breaks).

So testing routers is basically integration testing, not unit testing and is possible!